# How to fix this code

Tags: c++

**Please, how to fix this code**

```
[Error] a function-definition is not allowed here before '}' token

[Error] expected '}' at the end of input
```

I don't know what's the problem with my code even though I've already checked the compiler errors

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct name_type
{
    string first,middle,last;
};

struct SD
{
    name_type name;
    float grade;
};

const int MAX_SIZE = 35;

int isFull(int last) {
    if(last == MAX_SIZE - 1) {
        return(1);
    }
    else {
        return(0);
    }
}
int isEmpty(int last) {
    if(last < 0) {
        return(1); 
    }
    else {
        return(0);
    }
}


main()
{
    SD SD2[MAX_SIZE];
    int last = -1;

    if(isEmpty(last)) 
    {
        cout << "List is empty\n";
    }

    for (int a=0; a <35; a++)
    {
        cout << "Enter first name:.....";
        cin >> SD2[a].name.first;
        cout << "Enter middle name:....";
        cin >> SD2[a].name.middle;
        cout << "Enter last name:......";
        cin >> SD2[a].name.last;
        cout << "Enter your grade:.....";
        cin >> SD2[a].grade;
        cout << '\n';
    }
    system("cls");
    cout << "1 - Add";
    cout << "2 - Delete";
    cout << "3 - Search";
    cout << "4 - Print";
    cout << "5 - Exit";

    string lname, fname;
    int choice, search;
    cin >> choice;

    if(choice == 3) {
        cin >> fname;
        cin >> lname;
        int index = search;
        (SD2, lname, fname, last);

        if (index > 0) {
            cout << "ERROR\n";
        }
        else {
            cout << "The grade of " << lname << "," << fname << "is " << SD2[index].grade;
        }
    }

    int search(SD list [], string search_lname, string search_fname, int last) {
        int index;
        if(isEmpty(last)==1) {
            cout << "\nThe list is Empty!";
        }
        else {
            index = 0;
            while(index!= last+1 && list[index].name.first != search_fname && list[index].name.last != search_lname) {
                ++index;
            }
            if(index != last + 1) {
                cout << "\nItem Requested is Item" << index + 1 << ".";
                return index;
            }
            else {
                cout << "\n Item Does Not Exist.";
            }

        }
        return -1; // list is empty or search item does not exist
    }

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: When you write code, start with something small and simple that works perfectly, then add complexity a little at a time. Develop new functionality in isolation as much as possible. Test at every step, and **never add to code that doesn't work.**

Comment: The main() function cannot have a return value of type _void_.

Comment: As they have said, start with a small portion of code, then start creating the functions and test if they work and keep adding code until you get the error. No need to debug the entire program.

Comment: look at main().  block for: if(choice==3).  you have:  int index = search;  next line has the parameters...

Comment: To start with main(), should be int main().

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is in your declaration of the main function:

```
main()
```

In c++, the `main()` function **must** have a return type of `int`. Sin you have not specified any data type for the return value of `main()`, it sets the return data type to void, which is  produces the error just before `main()`. To learn and understand more about `main()` for C++, visit the following link [Main Function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function).

To sort this, change the above line of code to:

```
int main() // notice that the return type here is int. This is required in c++
```

Another thing: in these lines:

```
int index = search;
(SD2, lname, fname, last);
```

Over here, you want to pass `SD2`,  `lname`, `fname` and `last` to the  `search()` function. However, your syntax is wrong. The function and its parameters when called cannot be split by a semicolon, because a semicolon terminates the statement. Therefore, the compiler sees `search` as a variable, not a function. This along with the statement following it cause the error. You should change those 2 lines to:

```
int index = search(SD2, lname, fname, last); // this is proper syntax to call a function.
```

Also, you need to take out `search()` from inside the main() function and place it above the main() function. That is also causing an error.